# Is there any condition for a 2x2 system of equations to have a positive solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

A $2$x$2$ system of heterogeneous equations has a unique solution if and only if the determinant of the matrix of its coefficients be non-zero.

There is a $2$x$2$ system of heterogeneous equations and the variables are $x$ and $z^2$, I decided to convert the $z^2 = y$ and solve the system for $x, y$, Then square the solution to the $y$ to get the $z$.

I would like to know is there any thing that determines whether the $y$ has a positive solution?

Thanks in advance

### More Details

I am solving a problem and there is a recursive function $f(x)$ and another function $g(x)$. I need to solve this system of equations:

$$
af(a)-xf(a)-z^2g(a) = 0
$$
$$
bf(b)-xf(b)-z^2g(b) = 0
$$

clearly this system has solution if determinant of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
f(a)&g(a)\\
f(b)&g(b)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is non-zero, I set the $z^2 = y$. Since $y$ must be positive, I need other conditions to guarantee that $y \geq 0$ .

Comment: If you know the $2 \times 2$ matrix, it's pretty easy to write its inverse and therefore the whole solution. I'm sure if you write it down, you can then set the condition $y>0$ etc ...

Comment: As a follow-up on the comment of @Matti P. : provide more details, please, this question is very unclear in its current form. What is given as a concrete number in the problem, or as a parameter?

Comment: @MattiP. I didn't get it. if the matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}$$ then what conditions are sufficient for being positive of $y$?

Comment: @A.Pongrácz I provided more details

Comment: @MattiP. I provided more details

Comment: The answer depends on the RHS of the system, too. Are they not given?

Comment: @A.Pongrácz they are $af(a)$ and $bf(b)$ and $a < b$. In fact I am looking for solvability of this problem. Nothing else is given. just a recursive function

Comment: Use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems) to get that $f(a)f(b)$ and the determinant $f(a)g(b)-f(b)g(a)$ must have the same sign (subject to $a<b$).

Answer (score 1):

You can express the solution in terms of the parameters, using the general formula of the inverse matrix of a $2\times 2$ matrix, see for example: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html

There is no better way, this is the precise formula that provides you with the answer. You just have to check in this concrete case when the resulting $y$ is positive, which means you have to solve an inequality. There is no general recipee for this, it can be any inequality, depending on the parameters.